# Using annotation @LocalServerPort with ScalaTest in Scala + SpringBoot application

Tags: spring, scala, spring-boot

I am playing around with Scala and Spring Boot just to see how nicely these work with each other.

I could easily bootstrap Spring Boot application using Scala, here is entry point to app:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication

object Application extends App {
  SpringApplication.run(classOf[BootConfiguration])
}
```

and here is config class:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication

@SpringBootApplication
class BootConfiguration
```

So far so good. I could even easily add a test on top of that using Spring annotations:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Array(classOf[BootConfiguration]))
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class ApplicationSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers {

  "An application" should "bootstrap itself correctly" in {
    "lalalala" shouldEqual "lalalala"
  }
```

}

but I honestly have no idea how to make the use of the random port that is chosen during a setup of webEnvironment. Normally in java/groovy I could use an annotation  *@LocalServerPort* or *@Value("${local.server.port}")* and in a test class do something of this sort on one of class fields:

```
@LocalServerPort private int port
```

And that would do the trick. In Scala though it simply does not work, I tried using both *val* and *var*.

This thingy:

```
@LocalServerPort var port: Int = _
```

compiles but defaults port to 0, doing such a thing with *val* would obviously force me to declare a class test as an abstract class - not really what I have in mind. I can think of at least a few workarounds so I can still test this app nicely using ScalaTest but the whole point of this question is to make @LocalServerPort working. Thank you in advance for all suggestions!